# What does "systemd-timesyncd: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection mean"?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, systemd-timesyncd

I'm trying to debug some network connection issues and I see:

```
systemd-timesyncd: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
```

in syslog. I've tried to google it but I can't find a good definition of it. Is it something I need to worry about? Is the configuration change only in the context of `timesyncd`?
Thanks.

Comment: In what context did this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `journalctl --since "1 days ago"` to see what systemd reports before that change happens.

Are you running containers on this server? For me, it seems to happen any time Kubernetes schedules a container on or off a node. That might happen hundreds of times per day, and thus these log messages are obnoxious.

```
Jun 10 08:38:24 docker01 containerd[1206]: time="2021-06-10T18:38" level=info msg="shim containerd-shim started" address="unix:///run/containerd/s/asdasasdasdasdasasdasd
" debug=false pid=122
Jun 10 08:38:25 docker01 systemd-networkd[719]: cali1234: Link DOWN
Jun 10 08:38:25 docker01 systemd-networkd[719]: cali1234: Lost carrier
Jun 10 08:38:25 docker01 systemd-timesyncd[94670]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Jun 10 08:38:25 docker01 systemd-timesyncd[94670]: Synchronized to time server 10.11.12.13:123 (ntp01.example.org.nersc.gov).
Jun 10 08:38:25 docker01 systemd-timesyncd[94670]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Jun 10 08:38:25 docker01 systemd-timesyncd[94670]: Synchronized to time server 10.11.12.13:123 (ntp01.example.org.nersc.gov).
```

This appears related to the two following bugs and appears patched in systemd v239. Ubuntu 18.04 ships with systemd v237 and is unlikely to receive a fix.

- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8603

Comment: It's happening on `debian 12` with `systemd 252 (252.6-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also happen if you have more than one network interface.  By default systemd will not consider network initialization complete until all interfaces are brought up, meaning other services which depend upon networking will potentially be waiting indefinitely.  The solution is to override 'systemd-networkd-wait-online' service thus:

```
systemctl edit systemd-networkd-wait-online
```

add the following to the top of the file:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --any
```